# How to create NSDate that will be in DST mode

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsdate

I would like to know how it is possible to create NSDate that will be in DST mode.

I am using method `nextDaylightSavingTimeTransition`

This is from documentation:

> This property contains the date of the next (after the current
>   instant) daylight saving time transition for the receiver. Depending
>   on the time zone of the receiver, the value of this property may
>   represent a change of the time zone's offset from GMT. Returns nil if
>   the time zone of the receiver does not currently observe daylight
>   saving time.

And than i validate if it is in DST mode:

I am using method: `isDaylightSavingTimeForDate:`

This is from documentation:

> YES if the receiver uses daylight saving time at aDate, otherwise NO.

Code:

```
NSDate *nextDstTransition = [[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] nextDaylightSavingTimeTransition];


BOOL isDstOnForOldDate = [[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] isDaylightSavingTimeForDate:nextDstTransition];
```

Unfortunately my `nextDstTransition` is not in DST. My assumptions are connected with time zone problem.

Could you share you option about creation of the `NSDate` in DST mode.

Comment: 1) NSDate has not timezone or "DST mode". What are you trying to achieve? – 2) How are the 2 different variables  `nextDstTransition` and `oldWordate` related? – 3) Is the question for Objective-C or Swift?

Comment: @MartinR 1) Thx 2) I correct mistake 3) Answer could be in Swift or Objective-C

Comment: Currently DST is active, therefore nextDaylightSavingTimeTransition returns the next point in time at which DST ends, therefore isDaylightSavingTimeForDate returns false for that date. – What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: For test purpose i would like to create NSData that will be always in DST mode

Comment: NSDate has no "DST mode". It is just an absolute point in time (stored internally as the number of seconds since Jan 1, 2001 GMT).

Comment: So how than it is possible to create NSDate that will positively conform to isDaylightSavingTimeForDate always

Comment: As I said, NSDate knows *nothing* about DST. You would have to create a custom NSTimeZone. But I have no idea if/how that is doable.

Comment: To back up Martin R on this: NSDate is an opaque marker representing when something happened. Think: a count of the number of seconds since somebody started counting. Sometimes they were counting while it was DST. Sometimes they were counting while it wasn't. It makes zero difference to the count. They just counted every second that passed. `isDaylightSavingTimeForDate` will tell you whether, when a particular second was counted, the time zone you're querying was in daylight savings. So the answer will depend on the `NSDate`.

Comment: @Tommy  thx for response. I appreciate you're help i post my answer could you please share opinion if it is valid approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the documentation carefully: nextDaylightSavingTimeTransition: returns the next time when the DST changes after a given date, or nil if you are in time zone where DST never changes (either always on, or always off). If your date is in DST, then you are fine, otherwise you need to know when it changes.

```
NSDate* date = ...
if (! [[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] isDaylightSavingTimeForDate:date]) {
    NSDate* change = [[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] nextDaylightSavingTimeTransitionAfterDate:date];
    if (change != nil) {
        date = change;
    } else {
        // Tough, there is no DST in this time zone. 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After investigation and searching for the most elegant solution i understand that it is possible to do in this way.

```
//This is date object and from beginning we could make prediction that is is in DST Mode.    
NSDate *workDateInDST = [[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] nextDaylightSavingTimeTransition];
//Hear we could validate if it is DST or not
if (![[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] isDaylightSavingTimeForDate:workDateInDST]) {
    workDateInDST = [NSDate date];
}
```

Comment: *Now* I understand what you wanted. I would probably proceed the other way around. First test if the current date is in DST. If not, compute another date using nextDaylightSavingTimeTransition.

Comment: Please don't do that. "Serial upvoting" is detected on SO and reverted automatically. That leaves a bad impression in my reputation history.